# basic clang: sprintf resets int counter to 0

Tags: c

Consider the following:

```
int fileNo = 0;
sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", fileNo);
```

then later

```
fileNo++; // fileNo equals 1 now
```

Then if you call this again:

```
sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", fileNo);
```

`fileNo` now equals 0 again.

The goal here is to keep a counter in `fileNo`, and then pass that value to `sprintf` in order to set a filename. Is there an easier way to convert a counter to a string value? Or am I just missing a step that might prevent the `fileNo` from being reset to zero?

I've been digging into `malloc`, but it isn't really clear when that is necessary. Help?

(I'm not new to programming, but new to C.)

## Update

This is a very simple program. There are no reassignments. When I step into the debugger, fileNo is reset to 0 immediately after the `sprintf` line is executed.

...

```
static int fileNo = 0;
char outfile[7];
sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", fileNo);
```

...

```
 while(fread(buffer, 1, 512, inptr) == 512)
 {
    // 0xff 0xd8 0xff
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff)
    {
        if (!found1stJPG)
        {
            found1stJPG = true;

        } else {
            fileNo++;
            fclose(outptr);
            sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", fileNo); // fileNo is 1 before this executes
            printf("outfile: %s,\n", outfile); // in the debugger fileNo is now 0
        }
```

Comment: You will probably have to show more of your code but I suspect `fileNo` is going out of scope and then a new `fileNo` is instantiated with the value of `0`.  What happens if you change `int fileNo = 0;` to `static int fileNo = 0;`?

Comment: `sprintf` does not reset the counter to 0. Your code does. The part we can't see.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, or it will be almost impossible for us to help you.

Comment: @mttrb the static flag was what I needed. If you put that into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Note that making local variables `static` the functions become non-reentrant. If you want to call the function from two different contexts that should have their own counting, it will not work anymore with a `static` variable.

Comment: What code you have shown is correct; the conclusion you have drawn is incorrect; `sprintf` does not modify its parameters - how can it when they are passed by copy not by reference? Some other error in your code is doing that, or possibly you have two different `fileNo` variables in different scopes.  You have elided the code to the point that your real problem is not shown.  The answer is certainly not to make things even more complex with memory allocation - it is not even clear how you expect that to help.  Your approach to fault finding and solving is frankly a bit random.

Comment: @Kraken ;  mttrb _could_post an answer, but it would still be a _guess_ in the context of the question as it stands; first you should modify your question to include the information he asked for in order for such an answer to have sufficient context to make sense.  My advice is to use the debugger your toolchain almost certainly includes - you could then see that `sprintf` played no part in this error at all.

Comment: @Clifford: I conclude it's likely that he did indeed discover that sprintf wrote to fileno.

Comment: The sprintf overflows the buffer. You should use snprintf, and be aware that `%03d` specifies a *minimum width*, not a maximum

Comment: @Joshua : With the updated question, it is clear that the buffer was overrun and that declaring `fileNo` static "worked" merely by moving the variable to a different memory segment.  The bug remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following:

```
char somecharvariable;
char outfile[7];
int fileNo = 0;
sprintf(outfile, "%03d.jpg", fileNo);
```

Oops. The string null terminator wrote over fileno. outfile should be length 8. If you allow fileNo to exceed 999 your code will crash anyway.

Putting the static flag on fileNo does not fix the problem. It merely relocates the problem to some other variable.

Comment: *`outfile` should be length 8.* Even that's not a sufficient fix.  The `%03d` format string will result in *at least* three bytes being written to the output string.

Comment: Since a decimal representation of 32bit integer may have up to 10 digits an a sign, 16 would be a safe value, but since stack space is unlikely to be severely restricted in this case, I'd suggest a bit of headroom for maintenance - say 32.